# Finding the limit by factoring the denominator and canceling

Tags: calculus, limits, fractions

I have the problem 
$$\lim_{x\to10} \frac{x-3}{x^2+7x-30}$$

If I factor it to $\dfrac{x-3}{(x+10)(x-3)}$ then $x-3$ cancels and I'm left with $0$.

I know the real answer is $1/20$, but why is zero wrong?

Comment: At $x=10$ the denominator is finite because $x + 10 = 20$. Or have you cancelled the numerator to zero instead of 1? A more interesting question would be to find the limit as $x \to 3$.

Comment: When you cancel $x-3$, you end up with $\frac{1}{x+10}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your cancellation method needs an adjustment: 
$$\frac{a}{a\cdot b} = \frac{1}{b}, \quad \textbf{not} \frac{0}{b}$$
To see why, note that $a=a\cdot 1$, so
$$\frac{a}{a\cdot b} = \frac{a\cdot 1}{a\cdot b}= \frac{1}{b}$$

You may also want to experiment with $\dfrac{3}{2\cdot 3}$, for a concrete example.